# Connecting CCSprites in Cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm currently working on the interesting example in cocos2d. I have a sprite, that is a line, that just moving(with the help of CCAction) on my background. But the line is 4000 pixels wide. iOS 4.x is supporting not more then 2048 pixels by 2048 pixels. So I decided to cut the line in to two pieces. So, now I have two images, 1920 x 1920. Now I want to do the same thing that I did previously. This is really simple code:

```
CCSprite *abstractFigureLine = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Abstract Figures Line.png"];
    abstractFigureLine.position = CGPointMake(960.0f, 160.0f);
    [self addChild:abstractFigureLine z:1];
    CCAction *moveAbstractFigureLineAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:10.0f position:CGPointMake(-900.0f, 160.0f)];
    [abstractFigureLine runAction:moveAbstractFigureLineAction];
```

Now I need to insert the image of another sprite, as well really simple, but is there any way to connect this two sprites in to one single sprite?

Comment: Why not just draw the line with OpenGL? Ie ccDrawLine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base node for you sprites, add your sprites to this node, and run actions on this node:

```
CCSprite *abstractFigureLine1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Abstract Figures Line.png"];
abstractFigureLine.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

CGSize lineSize = [abstractFigureLine1 contensSize];
CCSprite *abstractFigureLine2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Abstract Figures Line.png"];
abstractFigureLine.position = CGPointMake(lineSize.width, 0);

CCNode *base = [[CCNode alloc] init];
[base setPosition: CGPointMake(960.0f, 160.0f)];

[base addChild:abstractFigureLine1 z:1];
[base addChild:abstractFigureLine2 z:1];

[self addChild:base z:1];

CCAction *moveAbstractFigureLineAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:10.0f position:CGPointMake(-900.0f, 160.0f)];
[base runAction:moveAbstractFigureLineAction];
```

Note, that CCSprite's position - is it's center, but CCNode's position - is it's bottom-left courner.

Comment: You can set any point on any CCNode subclass to position it. Just set it's isRelatieveAnchorPoint property to YES

Comment: I didn't find out why, but the lastest cocos2d sources have no such property. I just never use it.

Comment: In both 1.1.0 and 2.0 versions of cocos2d CCNode has property isRelativeAnchorPoint

Comment: I use box2d, so template provides PhysicSprite class, subclass of CCSprite. There was this property to use, and after update, there war an error on it "undefined property". May be it was renemed, or replaced. I jusst deleted it, and it worced fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with two sprites and at the end of action of first sprite start action of second spite.

Comment: This code is already in separated class. Now I will try it out.